# Install a specific stable Docker version

Tags: software-installation, docker

I want to install Docker in an older stable version: `17.03.2`.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and have added the docker community repository:

```
$ apt-cache madison docker-ce
 docker-ce | 18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
```

So there are only those two packages in the ubuntu dir. looking closely I compared the [debian](https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/pool/stable/amd64/) repository against the [new ubuntu](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/pool/stable/amd64/) and [old ubuntu](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/pool/stable/amd64/) repository.

I guess, I would have to compile docker myself. Estimating the effort, I think about switching to debian or an older ubuntu instead. [Maybe install the debian package](https://askubuntu.com/a/977181/712203) in ubuntu? Or is there a compile bot (using docker, k8 etc) for docker-ce that can easily build a release file?

What is the right way to install docker 17.03.2?

Answer (score 3):

If you explore the [download directories in docker.io](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/) you won't find a 17.03 compiled for Bionic, so there is no guarantee that 17.03 will work with Bionic...

You can however find a [.deb for Xenial](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/pool/stable/amd64/), so installing it in a VirtualBox running Xenial would be easy.

This said, why would you want a specific Docker version? Where I work there is a mix of Docker versions (from 12 to 18) (as well as several versions of the docker registry), and so far we haven't uncovered compatibility problems.