# How to go back to previous version of Thunderbird on 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird

On 15/10/2018, updates pulled a new version of Thunderbird (60.2.1). Unfortunately this version does not work with some important addons I rely on. What is the procedure to go back to the previous version (pre 60, not sure which version it was)? Thanks!

Comment: Check also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084059/latest-update-to-thunderbird-60-2-1-on-18-04-lightning-calendar-missing

Comment: You don't say what add-ons you're having trouble with. Maybe there's an easier solution.

Comment: This addon for example: https://github.com/ExchangeCalendar/exchangecalendar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Step 1 - Find the version you want**

**`apt policy` or `apt-cache policy`**  (or `apt-cache madison`)

e.g.

```
$ sudo apt policy thunderbird
thunderbird:
  Installed: 1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Candidate: 1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

So now we know (at this time) we have two versions:

- `1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2` and
- `1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1`

The three stars `***` indicates that this is the version *currently installed* as per the "Installed:" line.

**Step 2 - Install another version**

This is easy, just use the syntax **[packagename]=[version]** with `apt install`.

e.g.

```
$ sudo apt install thunderbird=1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  thunderbird-gnome-support ttf-lyx
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  thunderbird
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to downgrade, 0 to remove and 12 not to upgrade.
Need to get 46.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 38.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Note the **warning** that the package will be **DOWNGRADED**

**Bonus step - lock in that version**  (a.k.a. **apt-mark hold**)

If you want to stop `apt upgrade` from upgrading the package again, then you can tell apt to **hold** a package.

e.g.

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold thunderbird
thunderbird set on hold.
```

So now, when you `apt upgrade` you'll get a warning that packages have been **kept back**.  e.g.

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  thunderbird
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

When you are comfortable upgrading again, then you can release the hold:

```
$ sudo apt-mark unhold thunderbird
Cancelled hold on thunderbird.
```

e voila, the latest release is now the default again:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  thunderbird
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 41.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 38.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

You could also have gone with **apt pinning** and the `/etc/apt/preferences` file but *hold*ing is much easier for this task!

Comment: What about if a specific version does not appear?  That is, when I type `apt policy` I only get two subversions of release 68.

See, I am trying to get version 60.9 to appear in 19.10 and I can't.  I need to roll back to that version as it is the last one I  know where _nostalgy_ plugin works.

Comment: @JuanAntonio https://askubuntu.com/questions/977160/install-a-specific-version-version-not-listed-using-madison

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to solve it last night but I used a slightly different solution as I was unable to locate the deb files.  

1)I installed the mozillateam ppa repository, 2) found and installed the version I wanted, and 3) then marked the version using hold so that it would not be upgraded.

I pieced this together from a few different sources.

Comment: This is great -- with the caveat that the downgraded Thunderbird might refuse to start if the newer version has meddled with your profile.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by tudor-Reinstate Monica does work, but will typically roll you back to v.52, which is MUCH too far into the past.

The main problem is that Thunderbird is NOT making older versions available for download (see gripes about that here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1347599). Shame on the "open source" developers. However, you can reverse engineer the download link by changing the version number in the URL to get some installation materials. For example:

https://download.mozilla.org/?product=thunderbird-78.13.0-SSL&os=win64&lang=en-US
https://download.mozilla.org/?product=thunderbird-102.2.1-SSL&os=linux64&lang=en-US

Then, you can follow/modify the instructions here to install everything: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux#w_installing-from-your-distribution-package-manager-recommended

In my case (Ubuntu 18.04), thunderbird files were not in /opt, as per the above link, but in /usr/lib. Replacing these files with the rollback files did roll me back to the desired version without damaging my profile, so that was nice.

A roll-back option really should be provided, and all prior versions should be available to access.

Comment: Good answer, however when I tried install thunderbird following your advice it ignored my existing profile (and all the settings), and instead wanted me to configure a new account. Any advice on that?