# How to go downgrade Thunderbird to older version in 18.04?,

Tags: thunderbird, downgrade, japanese, lightning

My indispensable addons don't work in Thunderbird 60.x (Japanese popup readers rikaichan, rikaichamp, yomichan, etc.) nor in 52.x (lightning calendar) so I want to downgrade to an even older version when all was perfect. How can I do it? I read the thread about [downgrading Thunderbird to the PREVIOUS version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084391/how-to-go-back-to-previous-version-of-thunderbird-on-18-04) but I can't find how to downgrade even further. I don't know if older versions are still in the repositories and I should just find/guess the filename/version or if I have to install from another source. I had been patient to solve this in some eventual update but this unpleasant situation has not been resolved for too long and it was much more functional before. Please help!!

Comment: Hi Fermín. Maintainer of rikaichamp here. Thank you for your patience. If you can wait until July I plan to make rikaichamp work with Thunderbird then.

Comment: Off topic comment: one of the hardest study is reading Kanji characters, while I was the elementary school kid, I really reluctant to look up the character on the Kanji dictionary, and there're no alternative ways to know it by myself. Later I learned English and see the English-Japanese dictionary, I definitely choose English for my first language!!! While the brianskold the rikaichan author fix it, you can copy the word into Google chrome or Firefox and 反芻 that the computer today can understand plain text and even freehand writings or characters in the picture.

Comment: brianskold that's excellent news! It's been too many months of waiting and I was ready to give up... Thanks for the great work.

Comment: Sorry, this is still in progress. I'm currently a bit distracted with iOS support. It is on the list though.